# Debugging iOS version specific bugs

Tags: debugging, iphone-x

How can I go about fixing bugs that are specific to iPhoneX TestFlight testers (there are no testers without iPhoneX). They probably have the latest iOS version while I’m at 11.2.1 on iPhone 6. Bugs I cannot reproduce are things like tableview lag when scrolling, crash on home page when scrolling, not loading next page of home feed data. I presume these are issues attributed to their different device or version since I cannot reproduce. Would it be along the lines of finding the issue through integration of a tool like Sentry or Crashalytics, and adding if statements checking for current device iOS version? Thanks for any input. This is about standard procedure for debugging issues specific to iPhoneX or greater iOS versions.

Comment: I stopped being an iOS developer at the wrong time to be able to be authoritative about this, but Apple TestFlight is supposed to collect crash logs for you, and they're supposed to turn up in Xcode automatically. See e.g. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5396 . I assume that's not happening?

Comment: @Tommy thanks! There was one crash logged, and I was able to identify the method being called. However, Im still uneasy about the fact that I could not consistently reproduce it (if this is in fact the bug thats causing a crash every time on iPhoneX). Anyways, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.